# Why do universal recipients (AB blood group) not react to antibodies in the blood of O-group donors?

Tags: immunology

While studying compatible blood groups, I found that we only consider the antigens on red blood cells (RBCs) and not the antibodies present in blood plasma. For example

> “an AB blood group person can receive blood from persons of any blood group as there are
>   already both antigens, A and B, on the RBCs.”

But why don’t we consider the antibodies already present in the plasma from people with different blood groups?

For example, the O blood group has both anti-A and anti-B antibodies. If this blood is given to an AB person who has antigens A and B, do the antibodies of O not react with the antigens of AB?  Or, in other words, how is a person with the AB blood group a universal recipient if he has both antigens(A,B) in the blood, which can react with antibodies(anti-A and anti-B) present in indiduals of other blood groups (A, O, B)?

Comment: Always remember that plasma is not given while blood transfusion. So if you are giving only RBC of **O** blood group to the person having **AB** Blood group it will not react.

Comment: Although I answered this question, an [older similar question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26374/why-can-blood-group-o-be-given-to-all-blood-groups) has just surfaced for some reason. (The answer there is also more comprehensive than mine, and some comments more authoratitive.) I therefore flag this as a duplicate and have deleted my answer. (I may add something to the older question.)